# Swift Sprite Kit Add the amount of sprites per level

Tags: swift

I don't have any code, but I was just wondering how you would add sprites to your scene based on what level the game was at. For example: Level 1 would have 1 sprite, level 2 would have 2, level 3 would have 3....
I don't want to have to write out every single level as the game idea could go up to 100's of levels. 
I have a very simple idea in mind, but I can't seem to figure it out. 
I'm sorry if this is too vague, but I don't have any real code to include. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each level is essentially the same, except the number sprites, this is what I would recommend:

**1.** Create a subclass of `SKScene` that holds logic common to all your levels. For example:

```
class Level : SKScene {
    var numberOfSprites: Int = 0

    private func createSprites() {
        for _ in 0..<numberOfSprites {
            let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "YourSprite")
            // Setup anything else with the sprite, like the position.
            self.addChild(mySprite)
        }
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)
        createSprites()
    }

    private func levelIsComplete() {
        // Cell this when the level is complete to go to the next level.
        if let view = self.view {
            let nextLevel = Level(size: self.size)
            nextLevel.numberOfSprites = self.numberOfSprites + 1

            view.presentScene(nextLevel)
        }
    }
}
```

**2.** When creating your first level set the number of sprites to 1 and let it handle everything else.

```
let myLevel = Level(size: view.bounds.size)
myLevel.numberOfSprites = 1
```

**Here's it in action**

In my version I gave the sprites random positions and called `levelIsComplete` in `touchesBegan`.

[image]

Comment: if you had 100 levels, wouldn't you still have to write out that code at the bottom, 100 times?

Comment: thanks. I'll see if I can work with that and try to figure something out. Appreciate it.

Comment: I played around with it, but I can't figure out how to get the numberOfSprites to equal the sprites that I'm creating. I don't know if that makes sense. But let's say the sprite is a coin. I want 1 coin on level 1, 2 on level 2....It's probably right in front of me and I can see it!!!!

Comment: For that you could use a for loop. I'll add an example in my answer.